# How to avoid React markup checksum warnings when rendering time

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, isomorphic-javascript

When leveraging isomorphic rendering for a React component that displays time, I occasionally run into an issue where the server renders time at point `A`, but by the time the client picks up as a SPA, the time from point `A` has changed to point `B`, and React throws a `React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid` warning:

[image]

The occurrence of the error is obviously more pronounced as you display more granular time units like seconds, but it would be nice to be sure I won't run into this on minute, hour, day, etc. boundaries as well.

Is there a way to tell React on the client side, effectively, *"It's OK, this little portion of the DOM here can differ from the server side"*? Or perhaps another way I haven't thought of?

**More Detail**

I'm using the [React-Intl `FormattedRelative`](http://formatjs.io/react/#formatted-relative) component to display an item's creation date in a friendly fashion. The item's creation date of course stays the same between client and server (and gets passed to the client in a serialized Flux store), but the server render and client render time difference is just long enough that the rendered HTML frequently — but not always — differs.

Comment: You pretty much just need to make sure that your initial clientside render call is with the EXACT same data as the serverside render.  This data differing is the only way a checksum error can occur.  So always render clientside with the snapshot of data from the server, and then hook in to any data changes that may have occurred AFTER that initial render.

Comment: I know that's why it's happening, but I'm rendering something that's inherently progressing. The error is introduced between the time the server finishes rendering and the client finishes rendering.

Comment: Right well you need to do something where you ignore the fact that your data is changing for that initial client render, even if it's incorrect.  Otherwise you will continue to see this error.  Ways I've got around this in the past is for example when using Flux, I initialize clientside flux stores based on  data json sent within the page html from the server which corresponds exactly to the data structure used to render on serverside.  I render once with this data, and then I bootstrap my rest api connections afterward.

Comment: Of course your other option is NOT to render serverside components based on parts of your data which are progressing.  Perhaps rendering a "loading" state from the server initially for the relevant components - then bootstrapping that data only from the clientside.

Comment: I am using Flux (via Marty.js), and the data I'm displaying is a bunch of Date objects coming from a server-dehydrated and client-rehydrated store, but the issue is cropping up because what `render()` returns differs as time progresses.

Comment: Right but the data at renders can differ, just not the initial client side render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with React Intl v2. It adds a `initialNow` property to stabilize the rendered times.

> A new feature has been added to `<FormattedRelative>` instances in React Intl v2, they now "tick" and stay up to date. Since time moves forward, it was confusing to have a prop named now, so it has been renamed to `initialNow`. Any `<FormattedRelative>` instances that use now should update to prop name to `initialNow`:

Usage:

```
<FormattedRelative value={date} initialNow={Date.now()}/>
```

You can also provide this on `IntlProvider` in which case all `FormattedRelative` instances are stabilized.

> Note: The `<IntlProvider>` component also has a `initialNow` prop which can be assigned a value to stabilize the "now" reference time for all `<FormattedRelative>` instances. This is useful for universal/isomorphic apps to proper React checksums between the server and client initial render.

Usage:

```
<IntlProvider initialNow={Date.now()}>
  <FormattedRelative value={date}/>
</IntlProvider>
```

Reference: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Upgrade-Guide#update-how-relative-times-are-formatted

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the data is going to change as soon as it renders client side, there is no point rendering that chunk server side.

So make a little component that renders this portion of information, but only by doing a force_update after mounting.

Before mount just put whatever you would like the user to see for the instant before rendering completes